# Providing a HTTP proxy for users in another continent

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, haproxy

I have a server located in Europe but our customer-base in South America is growing a lot.

I soon realized that many ISPs in South America have random international routing issues. Meaning that our customers will simply have issues to connect to our server. Sometimes this lasts a few minutes, sometimes it lasts several hours.

Anyway, it's hard to explain to the customer why he can access all websites located in his country and many others while he can't access our server.

At this point, it's not viable to separate my application and run at servers in South America. So i was looking into the option of renting Linux servers in a reliable DC ( without routing issues ) and proxy all connections from our users.

To do this i took a look at HA Proxy + a DNS server with geolocation. Is this the easiest way of doing it?

Are there any other softwares or services that would work better in this situation?

Not only free/open-source. It can be paid as long as it works.

Comment: An anycast DNS server would be better for this use case than a geolocating DNS server, but I guess you're unlikely to have custody of a block of portable IP addresses to use for that.

Comment: Or add another routing path to your server by adding a backup link via another provider.  Or perhaps add

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, as it's the connectivity that's at fault running a proxy will probably not help. It might be worth checking what ISPs are in the path, and if switching would improve things.

You may still get an improvement by running a second site in the US (DC's there are cheaper and more reliable) and caching data to save the trans-atlantic latency hit.